# Getting unhandled Promise rejection when I already throw err in the catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise

In my redux I got this axios get call As you can see I already throw the err here

```
export const getShippingMethodById = (token, id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        };
        return axios
            .get(`${baseUri}/api/checkout/GetShippingById?addressId=${id}`, config)
            .then((res) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_SHIPPING_METHOD_BY_ID,
                    payload: res.data.shippingInfos,
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
                alert('Cannot connect to server');
            });
    };
};
```

In the functional component , inside the useEffect hooks I am calling this function

```
useEffect(() => {
    let splitText = cartList?.OrderDTO?.DeliveryCountry;
    let deliveryAddressId = splitText?.split(',');
    if (
      cartList.OrderDTO?.DeliveryCountry !== '' &&
      deliveryAddressId !== undefined
    ) {
      dispatch(
        getShippingMethodById(token.access_token, Number(deliveryAddressId[1])),
      ).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    } else {
      dispatch(
        getShippingMethodById(
          token.access_token,
          cartList.OrderDTO?.CustomerAddressId,
        ),
      ).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    }
  }, [cartList]);
```

But when ever this component is loaded
I got this error

Since I already handle the promise rejection Why am I getting this error?

[image: Error Screen shot]

Comment: What do you think `throw` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing an error from a `catch` won't be caught by the same catch block being executed. This means you are returning a Promise rejection to your UI code and the error should then be caught there. Add a `catch` to the Promise chain.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let splitText = cartList?.OrderDTO?.DeliveryCountry;
  let deliveryAddressId = splitText?.split(',');
  if (
    cartList.OrderDTO?.DeliveryCountry !== '' &&
    deliveryAddressId !== undefined
  ) {
    dispatch(
      getShippingMethodById(token.access_token, Number(deliveryAddressId[1])),
    ).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    }).catch(error => {
      // handle rejected Promise or any other error from this chain
    });
  } else {
    dispatch(
      getShippingMethodById(
        token.access_token,
        cartList.OrderDTO?.CustomerAddressId,
      ),
    ).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    }).catch(error => {
      // handle rejected Promise or any other error from this chain
    });
  }
}, [cartList]);
```

Or simply remove rethrowing the error:

```
return axios
  .get(`${baseUri}/api/checkout/GetShippingById?addressId=${id}`, config)
  .then((res) => {
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_SHIPPING_METHOD_BY_ID,
      payload: res.data.shippingInfos,
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    // no error rethrow
    alert('Cannot connect to server');
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `throw err;` in `catch` block. You need to remove it. You can read more about `throw` in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw